# In MediaBrowserService.onLoadChildren, when/how is the options bundle supplied?

Tags: android, mediabrowserservicecompat, mediabrowserservice, mediabrowser

In `MediaServiceBrowser` or `MediaServiceBrowserCompat`, there are two methods:

`public abstract void onLoadChildren (String parentId, 
                Result<List<MediaBrowser.MediaItem>> result)`

and

`public void onLoadChildren (String parentId, 
                Result<List<MediaBrowser.MediaItem>> result, 
                Bundle options)`

`options` is described as:

> Bundle: The bundle of service-specific arguments sent from the media browser. The information returned through the result should be affected by the contents of this bundle. This value must never be null.

I hoped that providing extras into the `MediaDescriptionCompat` of the `MediaItem` (the one whose children are being loaded) would surface them in the second call.

However, only the first method is called, as tested under Android Auto.

What do I need to do to get called with an `options` argument?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: I don't work in this area much any more but no, I don't think I ever did find an answer. I think I probably found some other way of communicating the information to where it needed to be.